# Timeshift stuck on creating first snapshot

Tags: linux, backup, timeshift

The snapshot does not progresses:

```
sudo timeshift  --create --verbose --debug --comments "primeiro snapshot" --tags D
[sudo] senha para vfbsilva: 
D: Main()
D: 
D: Running Timeshift v24.01.1
D: 
D: Session log file: /var/log/timeshift/2024-02-05_19-28-48_ondemand.log
D: Distribution: EndeavourOS rolling (rolling)
D: DIST_ID: EndeavourOS
D: Main: check_dependencies()
[Warning] Deleted invalid lock
D: Main: add_default_exclude_entries()
D: Main: add_default_exclude_entries(): exit
D: update_partitions()
D: df -T -B1
D: Device: get_disk_space_using_df(): 4
D: Device: get_mounted_filesystems_using_mtab(): 4
D: Device: get_filesystems(): 15
D: partition list updated
D: detect_system_devices()
D: /home is mapped to device: /dev/sda1, UUID=20222e6c-dd7e-446f-bb5e-f555de3268d6
D: / is mapped to device: /dev/sdd1, UUID=b6e13729-035b-443d-9b44-53aa6ac3ce37
D: /boot/efi is mapped to device: /dev/sdd2, UUID=C762-BFAB
D: Searching subvolume for system at path: /
D: Users: root vfbsilva
D: Encrypted home users: 
D: Encrypted home dirs:

D: Encrypted private dirs:

D: Main: load_app_config()
D: Member not found in JSON object: snapshot_size
D: Member not found in JSON object: snapshot_count
App config loaded: /etc/timeshift/timeshift.json
D: IconManager: init()
D: found images directory: /usr/share/timeshift/images
D: Main(): ok
D: AppConsole: parse_arguments()
D: Main: initialize_repo()
D: backup_uuid=58b64c7f-b0c9-433d-baeb-3d9da4a3f4c2
D: backup_parent_uuid=
D: Setting snapshot device from config file
D: repo: creating from uuid
D: SnapshotRepo: from_uuid(): RSYNC
D: uuid=58b64c7f-b0c9-433d-baeb-3d9da4a3f4c2
D: SnapshotRepo: init_from_device()
D: 
D: SnapshotRepo: unlock_and_mount_devices()
D: device=/dev/sdb1
D: SnapshotRepo: unlock_and_mount_device()
D: device=/dev/sdb1
D: Device: get_mounted_filesystems_using_mtab(): 4
D: ------------------
D: arg=58b64c7f-b0c9-433d-baeb-3d9da4a3f4c2, device=/dev/sdb1
D: /run/timeshift/13944/backup
D: /run/timeshift/13289/backup
D: /run/timeshift/12917/backup
D: /run/timeshift/12665/backup
D: ------------------
D: Device: get_mounted_filesystems_using_mtab(): 4
Mounted '/dev/sdb1' at '/run/timeshift/16731/backup'
D: SnapshotRepo: load_snapshots()
D: loading snapshots from '/run/timeshift/16731/backup/timeshift/snapshots': 0 found
D: SnapshotRepo: unlock_and_mount_device(): exit
D: Selected snapshot device: /dev/sdb1
D: Free space: 166.8 GB
D: SnapshotRepo: check_status()
D: SnapshotRepo: available()
D: is_available: ok
D: SnapshotRepo: has_snapshots()
D: SnapshotRepo: has_space() - 0 required (0 B)
D: df -T -B1 '/dev/sdb1'
D: Device: get_disk_space_using_df(): 1
D: no snapshots
D: SnapshotRepo: check_status(): exit
D: SnapshotRepo: init_from_device(): exit
D: SnapshotRepo: from_uuid(): exit
D: Main: initialize_repo(): exit
D: AppConsole: start_application()
D: Main: create_snapshot()
D: SnapshotRepo: has_space() - 0 required (0 B)
D: df -T -B1 '/dev/sdb1'
D: Device: get_disk_space_using_df(): 1
D: no snapshots
D: Main: backup_and_rotate()
D: SnapshotRepo: available()
D: is_available: ok
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Estimating system size...
D: estimate_system_size()
D: Using temp dir '/tmp/oE3msrRA'
D: Main: save_exclude_list_for_backup()
D: Main: create_exclude_list_for_backup()
D: Main: create_exclude_list_for_backup(): exit
D: export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 ; rsync -ai --delete --numeric-ids --relative --stats --dry-run --delete-excluded --exclude-from='/tmp/oE3msrRA/exclude.list' /. '/tmp/oE3msrRA/empty' &> '/tmp/oE3msrRA/rsync.log'
D: First snapshot size: 138.0 GB
D: File count: 993462
D: Main: save_app_config()
D: SnapshotRepo: available()
D: is_available: ok
D: SnapshotRepo: has_snapshots()
App config saved: /etc/timeshift/timeshift.json
D: estimate_system_size(): ok
Creating new snapshot...(RSYNC)
Saving to device: /dev/sdb1, mounted at path: /run/timeshift/16731/backup
D: Main: save_exclude_list_for_backup()
D: Main: create_exclude_list_for_backup()
D: Main: create_exclude_list_for_backup(): exit
Syncing files with rsync...
D: RsyncTask:execute()
D: export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
rsync -aii --recursive --verbose --delete --force --stats --sparse --delete-excluded --log-file='/run/timeshift/16731/backup/timeshift/snapshots/2024-02-05_19-28-49/rsync-log' --exclude-from='/run/timeshift/16731/backup/timeshift/snapshots/2024-02-05_19-28-49/exclude.list' --delete-excluded '/' '/run/timeshift/16731/backup/timeshift/snapshots/2024-02-05_19-28-49/localhost/'
D: RsyncTask:prepare(): saved: /tmp/oE3msrRA/2024-02-05_19-28-57/script.sh
D: AsyncTask: child_pid: 16794
0.00% complete
```